# Download from brightcove URL button

Tags: url, button, download, brightcove, save-as

I am creating a site that utilizes videos that are hosted on brightcove so that our sales team can access these and post them to other retail sites.  I have included a Download URL text area on the page that give the long URL of the selected video that if pasted into the browser, one can save the video as straight to their computer.  I am needing to created a button that when clicked will automatically bring up the save as window on a persons computer so that it can be downloaded, or just a download button that will automatically start a download will work.  Any suggestions?

pradcomedia.com/brightcove/videomanager.html

```
<div>
<textarea id="divMeta.render" style="height:75px; width: 225px; resize: none;"></textarea>
</div> </br>


function urlLink(id){
document.getElementById('divMeta.render').innerHTML = url;
var link = window.open;


//renditions Metadata

    document.getElementById('divMeta.render').innerHTML = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the end users are using [browsers that support the download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) then you can just use that

```
<a href="http://example.com/video.mp4" download>Download me</a>
```